# Contador de letras repetidas em java

Tags: java, lista

Fiz um método para contar as letras repetidas que estão armazenadas e ordenadas alfabeticamente dentro de uma lista. O método esta contando certo mas o bug é na hora da impressão, ele printa a letra e a quantidade de vezes que aparece na frase corretamente o problema é que ele printa o mesmo elemento na mesma quantidade de vezes que o seu contador.

> Ex:a:3 aparece 3 vezes
>
> Ele printa:a:3
>               a:3
>               a:3
>
> Frase usada de exemplo:"Vê se tira notas boas!"

**Metodo:**

```
public void imprimir(){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.mensagem.size(); i++){
        int cont = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < this.mensagem.size(); y++){
            if(mensagem.get(i) == mensagem.get(y)) cont++;
        }
        System.out.println(mensagem.get(i)+":"+cont);
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

!:1
a:3
a:3
a:3
b:1
e:1
i:1
n:1
o:2
o:2
r:1
s:3
s:3
s:3
t:2
t:2
v:1
ê:1

Comment: Você quer contar letras repetidas em uma frase e depois mostrar o resultado?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Como contar a quantidade de ocorrências de uma String em um JSONArray?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236319/como-contar-a-quantidade-de-ocorr%C3%AAncias-de-uma-string-em-um-jsonarray/236561#236561)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separe as operações em dois métodos, uma vai **contar** e o outro vai **mostrar**, nunca faça uma coisa só, nesse caso primeiramente o código tem que varrer toda o **texto** e ir calculando até acabar para depois mostrar o resultado, utilize também estruturas para armazenar cada letra, ***exemplo***:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class JavaApplication3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "Vê se tira notas boas!";
        Map<String, Integer> map = contar(s.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase());
        Imprimir(map);
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> contar(String frase)
    {        
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();                
        for(char item : frase.toCharArray())
        {
            Integer s = map.get(String.valueOf(item));
            if (s != null)
            {
                map.put(String.valueOf(item), ++s);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(String.valueOf(item), 1);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void Imprimir(Map<String, Integer> items)
    {       
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a : items.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(a.getKey() + ": " +  a.getValue());
        }    
    }    
}
```

[Um exemplo ONLINE](https://ideone.com/bb8IDR)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Conhecendo a interface Map do Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conhecendo-a-interface-map-do-java/37463)
- [java.util.HashMap.entrySet() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_entryset.htm)
- [Class TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar as `Collections` do `Java` em seu favor da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, Integer> ocorrencias;

  ocorrencias = contar("Vê se tira notas boas!");
  ocorrencias.forEach((chave, valor) -> System.out.print(chave + ":" + valor + " "));
}

private static Map<String, Integer> contar(String frase) {
  Map<String, Integer> resultado = new TreeMap<>(); // TreeMap para manter o Map ordenado pelas chaves
  List<String> ocorrencias;
  Set<String> letras;

  ocorrencias = Arrays.asList(frase.replace(" ", "").split("")); // Transforma a frase em uma lista que facilitará a contagem
  letras = new TreeSet<>(ocorrencias); // Pega as letras sem duplicidade 

  // Percorre o array de letras sem repetição contando as ocorrências
  letras.forEach((String letra) -> {
    resultado.put(letra, Collections.frequency(ocorrencias, letra));
  });

  return resultado;
}
```

O código acima produz:

> ```
> !:1 V:1 a:3 b:1 e:1 i:1 n:1 o:2 r:1 s:3 t:2 ê:1
> ```

O `TreeSet` não permite valores duplicados, sendo ótimo para guardar as letras sem repetição. Então um `Map` é preenchido com o valor contado pelo método `frequency`.

Veja funcionando no [**Ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/eAIHVj).

---

**Observação:** Note que seu método contar maiúsculas, minúsculas e acentuadas como sendo letras diferentes. Caso queira contas as ocorrências desprezando acentos, maiúsculas e minúsculas, utilize um método que realiza as conversões antes da contagem da seguinte forma:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> contar2(String frase) {
  String normalizado = Normalizer.normalize(frase, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
  String semAcentos = normalizado.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
  frase = semAcentos.toUpperCase();

  return contar(frase);
}
```

Que produz o seguinte resultado (utilizando o mesmo `main` de antes):

> ```
> !:1 A:3 B:1 E:2 I:1 N:1 O:2 R:1 S:3 T:2 V:1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Isso está acontecendo porque toda vez que você encontra uma letra, você está contando quantas vezes ela aparece e imprime.
No seu exemplo, ele encontra o "a" 3 vezes, e, nas 3 vezes, ele conta quantas tem e imprime.

Você pode criar um mapa e antes de contar quantas vezes a letra aparece, verificar se já foi contado. Assim você deixa o seu código mais rápido também, evitando que refaça o mesmo trabalho.